# How can I make an index system out of this system? Unity C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I've done a system for tower building with help of brackeys tutorial. I want to select towers by index of scriptable object but i can't use arrays in TurretBP.

TurretBP is storing all the turret data

Buildmanager instantiates turres

And SelectTurret() method attached to buttons

Here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Shop : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TurretBP turret; 
    public TurretBP Jamsheed;
    public TurretBP Farm;
    public TurretBP Otbaphou;
    public TurretBP Guard;
    public int turretIdx;

    BuildManager buildManager;

    private void Start()
    { 
        buildManager = BuildManager.instance;
    }


    public void SelectTurret()
    {
        buildManager.SelectTurretToBuild(turret);
    }

    public void SelectJamsheed()
    {
        buildManager.SelectTurretToBuild(Jamsheed);
    }

    public void SelectFarm()
    {
        buildManager.SelectTurretToBuild(Farm);
    }

    public void SelectOtbaphou()
    {
        buildManager.SelectTurretToBuild(Otbaphou);
    }

    public void SelectGuard()
    {
        buildManager.SelectTurretToBuild(Guard);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use arrays (idk why you've written that you can't):

```cs
    [SerializeField] private TurretBP[] towers; 

    public enum Towers
    {
        TURRET = 0,
        JAMSHEED = 1,
        FARM = 2,
        OTBAPHOU = 3,
        GUARD = 4
    }

    public TurretBP GetTower(int index)
    {
        return towers[index];
    }
```

Then you can call `buildManager.SelectTurretToBuild(GetTower(Towers.Guard));`
or `buildManager.SelectTurretToBuild(GetTower(4));`